# Container runtime is not running: output: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, cluster-computing

Basically I'm trying to create a cluster with my Ubuntu machine as a master and two Raspberry PI 3 as worker nodes and deploy a trained ML algorithm on my cluster, but all I get are errors when trying to initialize the master. I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall docker and  kubernetes, I've tried the kubeadl reset command and plenty other solutions.

When running journalctl -xe it seems like the error is this
    [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
since it's all in red, but I've provided below the full output of the commands used.

```
    sudo kubeadm init --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.1
    [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.16.0
    [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
    KERNEL_VERSION: 4.15.0-64-generic
    CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
    CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
    CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
    CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
    CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
    CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
    CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
    CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
    CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
    CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
    CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
    CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
    CONFIG_INET: enabled
    CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
    CONFIG_PROC_FS: enabled
    CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
    CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled (as module)
    CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
    CONFIG_AUFS_FS: enabled (as module)
    CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
    OS: Linux
    CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
    CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
    CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
    CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
    CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
    CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
    error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    , error: exit status 1
        [ERROR Service-Docker]: docker service is not active, please run 'systemctl start docker.service'
        [ERROR IsDockerSystemdCheck]: cannot execute 'docker info': exit status 1
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip_forward]: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: failed executing "docker info --format '{{json .}}'"\noutput: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    \nerror: exit status 1
    [preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
    To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher





    sudo systemctl start docker.service
    A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.




    -- The system clock has been changed to REALTIME microseconds after January 1st, 1970.
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-keyring-daemon[2655]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-session[2952]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1003/keyring/ssh
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-session[2952]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1003/keyring/ssh
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-keyring-daemon[2655]: The SSH agent was already initialized
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-session[2952]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1003/keyring/ssh
    sep 23 12:14:37 master01 gnome-keyring-daemon[2655]: The Secret Service was already initialized
    sep 23 12:14:38 master01 gnome-session-binary[2952]: Entering running state
    sep 23 12:14:38 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (process:3140): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Unable to get watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'
    sep 23 12:14:38 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (process:3140): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Name Lost
    sep 23 12:14:42 master01 gnome-session[2952]: sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right
    sep 23 12:14:42 master01 pulseaudio[2932]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ERROR        rabbitvcs.services.checkerservice        org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.google.code.rabbitvcs.RabbitVCS.Checker was not 
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/services/checkerservice.py", line 265, in _connect_to_checker
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     OBJECT_PATH)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     'su', (bus_name, flags)))
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     message, timeout)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.google.code.rabbitvcs.RabbitVCS.Checker was not provided by any .service files
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py", line 197, in __init__
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     self.status_checker.assert_version(EXT_VERSION)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/services/checkerservice.py", line 280, in assert_version
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]:     pid = self.status_checker.CheckVersionOrDie(version)
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CheckVersionOrDie'
    sep 23 12:14:45 master01 gnome-session[2952]: Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
    sep 23 12:20:17 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/nm/.face': No such file or director
    sep 23 12:20:17 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/mihaiscutaru/.face': No such file o
    sep 23 12:20:17 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/ifdstudent/.face': No such file or 
    sep 23 12:20:17 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/ken/.face': No such file or directo
    sep 23 12:20:17 master01 gnome-session[2952]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:34 master01 gnome-session[2952]: ** (nautilus:3142): CRITICAL **: nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_INFO_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:24:36 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (nautilus:3142): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
    sep 23 12:43:09 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/nm/.face': No such file or director
    sep 23 12:43:09 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/mihaiscutaru/.face': No such file o
    sep 23 12:43:09 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/ifdstudent/.face': No such file or 
    sep 23 12:43:09 master01 gnome-session[2952]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3143): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Couldn't open user icon: Failed to open file '/home/ken/.face': No such file or directo
    sep 23 12:43:09 master01 gnome-session[2952]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Here are the docker information in case that they are important

```
    Client:
     Version:           18.06.2-ce
     API version:       1.38
     Go version:        go1.10.3
     Git commit:        6d37f41
     Built:             Sun Feb 10 03:48:06 2019
     OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
     Experimental:      false
    Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

And here are the kubernetes information in case that they are important as well

```
kubeadm version -o=json
{
  "clientVersion": {
    "major": "1",
    "minor": "16",
    "gitVersion": "v1.16.0",
    "gitCommit": "2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77",
    "gitTreeState": "clean",
    "buildDate": "2019-09-18T14:34:01Z",
    "goVersion": "go1.12.9",
    "compiler": "gc",
    "platform": "linux/amd64"
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your current linux user is added to docker group. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my current issue, but now another one popped up. I've detalied it below.

Comment: @Alex could you please describe that another issue? Or if it is complex, please consider creating an another question.